# Good software to take a blog and format it for printing

Tags: conversion, printing, blogging

I have much of my family's doings on a Blogspot blog.  I would like to print this out in a nice book.

The actual printing I plan to just send to CostCo as Photo Prints.

But I need some kind of software to reformat the posts into printable paper size sheets.  I would like it if I could retain my blog's background and let me adjust how the pictures fit on the screen.

Now I could do all of this with MS Publisher or Word.  But I am curious if there is any other software out there that does this nice and easy.

Anyone know of some cool software that will do this for me?  Free is nice, but I am not above paying a modest fee for cool software.  I would prefer to avoid another website that will charge for the printing as well as the converting.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider [Clippable](http://brettterpstra.com/share/readability2.html). (Edit: aka, Readability2)

It's a piece of javascript magic that strips pages of fluff, leaving just the text and relevant images.

(To use, click and drag the "Clippable" link to your bookmarks bar. Then visit a news page, say http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/, and press the bookmark link).

You would have to modify it to keep your background, or just add it yourself afterwards. Whatever solution you chose it will probably involve some manual tweaking.

Comment: "Readability" is also nice, in this kind of manipulation: http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/ (it gets rid of all images, including background, though)

Comment: +1 for readabillity. May do what you need very well if you can live without the images.