# How would I convert a whole web site to PDF?

Tags: pdf, web

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Looking for software to facilitate printing of online content](https://superuser.com/questions/21541/looking-for-software-to-facilitate-printing-of-online-content)
>   [How can I download an entire website](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

Hi,

I'm looking for something that I can point at a URL and it crawl the site and create a single PDF of the of the site.

I would imagine it would be something like a Firefox plugin .. but with similar capabilities to wget.

**edit**

Good grief... how ready we are to close on superuser. I'm looking for a combination of both printing and crawling. I can crawl a site and download it via `wget`, and I can print to pdf (via pdf create). I'm looking for a combination of them both.. even if I need to wget to a bunch of .html then do something else.

The reason why I'd like it automated is that I need it quickly (within 30 minutes would be good) and we're talking 100+ pages.

One very valid point was that the order would be very hard to control. It's not so relevent here as one of the actual use cases is to print out all the site and spread it out on the table and rip through it with red pens making adjustments.

Oh... and the possible dupes pointed out.. some are possible dupes of other questions... none are really canonical answers.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/125222/good-software-to-take-a-blog-and-format-it-for-printing http://superuser.com/questions/21541/looking-for-software-to-facilitate-printing-of-online-content

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/22191/downloading-complete-web-pages-not-sites http://superuser.com/questions/55040/save-a-single-web-page-with-background-images-with-wget http://superuser.com/questions/34648/saving-blog-items-as-pdfs http://superuser.com/questions/79773/how-to-turn-webpages-into-pdf

Comment: So are we closing or what?

Comment: Just trying to spread the 3k vote close love around. And was looking for other dupes. @jos

Comment: @ran: Tell me about it! Since you and quack have the magic close vote there's barely anything to do. :)

Comment: Depending on where you work being asked to *"print out the internets"* might be a totally valid problem though.

Comment: the First link for duplicate was deleted for some reason but is available here: http://web.archive.org/web/20090904201616/https://superuser.com/questions/21541/looking-for-software-to-facilitate-printing-of-online-content

Answer (score 0):

try ACROBE ADOBE PRO

you can download from ADOBE Website as trial for 30 days-

install and then go to option Create PDF > From Web Page button.

Comment: He asked for a site, not a single web page.

Comment: uhmm, but that's not possible.(beggining that not in the whole website is possible navigate) I just bring to him a program from adobe. for convert the pages that he need.

Comment: Of course it's not possible (I explained it to him in my answer), but I don't think he's online anymore. Don't understand what's with the maniacal downvoter though ;)

Comment: For what it's worth, it is possible to use this option to download an entire site - there is just an 'entire site' radio button and then it will follow links and render those pages as well.  Not convinced it is the best way however as I tried it on a very simple 5 page site and it took ages.  Also for responsive sites, I couldn't see how to specify the width of the browser so the renders I got were for the mobile version of the site only

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do that.

(Before you object) ... it's not so much as a problem of *converting* to PDF, but more of a problem of how would that PDF be structured. How would a convertion program know which page (from some link) goes where (in what order).

I guess, some more problems would arise, but this is the first that sprang to mind.